# Sum a variable with a random number in the loop

Tags: java, java-console

I am generating a random number between 1 and 6. And I have an integer value with a value of 0 (int number1 = 0;). I need to add them in a loop. Each round of the loop the random number will be generated again and add on top of the previous sum. How can I write in JAVA (console).

will continue until a sum  of 100

```
int number1 = 0;
int number2 = (int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1);
```

for example: if number2 come 3 number1 (0) + number2 (3) = 3
and next tour if number2 come 4 number1 (3) + number2 (4) = 7

Comment: `int sum = 0; for(int i = 0; i < maxIter; i++){ sum+=(int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1); } return sum;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many ways to do it. A simple way to do it is by using an infinite loop which you can break when `number1 == 100`. It's also important to check `if (number1 > 100)` after adding a random number and remove that random number if it `true`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1 = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Current value: " + number1);
            if (number1 == 100) {
                break;
            }
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
            number1 += random;
            if (number1 > 100) {
                number1 -= random;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Current value: 0
Current value: 4
Current value: 9
Current value: 13
Current value: 19
Current value: 24
Current value: 29
Current value: 35
Current value: 39
Current value: 43
Current value: 48
Current value: 51
Current value: 57
Current value: 58
Current value: 62
Current value: 66
Current value: 70
Current value: 74
Current value: 79
Current value: 85
Current value: 88
Current value: 93
Current value: 97
Current value: 97
Current value: 98
Current value: 98
Current value: 100
```

To avoid casting the generated random numbers to `int`, I recommend you use [`Random#nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) as shown below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1 = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Current value: " + number1);
            if (number1 == 100) {
                break;
            }
            int random = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            number1 += random;
            if (number1 > 100) {
                number1 -= random;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned how to do it thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

**WHILE LOOP**:

```
int number1 = 0;
int loop = 6;

while (loop > 0){
    number1 += (int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1);
    loop--;
}
```

**FOR LOOP**:

```
int number1 = 0;
int loop = 6;

for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++){
    number1 += (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will do. You didn't specify when you want it to end so here is an example that runs 10 iterations:

```
int number1 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    number1 += (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
}
```

You can also user Random:

```
int number1 = 0;
Random random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    number1 += random.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 - Using do-while loop**

```
int sum =0;
do{
    sum += (int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1);
  }while(sum < 100);
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

**Method 2 - Using while loop**

```
int sum =0;
while(sum < 100){
     sum += (int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1);
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

**Method 3 - Using for loop**

```
int sum;
for(sum = 0; sum < 100;){
    sum += (int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1);
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a simpler solution with just one variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 6){
    number += (int) (Math.random () * 6 + 1);
}
```